# Install entire database (including binaries) inside A VOLUME in Docker

Tags: docker, containers, janusgraph

I need to containerize a JanusGraph database inside Docker, i don't know what files/directories needs to reside in volume to become persistent/writable. In order to make all the things simple and fast, can i install the entire database in a volume? Not only the data, but the entire app, all the binaries etc. I think this is a fast way to containerize some of my apps.

The janusGraph subdirectories of binaries, data, log resides inside a "janusgraph-hadoop" directory

For example: i will create a volume called /janusgraph-hadoop and run the command to install all the software inside that (it will be a volume).

This can be considered a bad practice or there are no problem in doing that?

I know, we have some JanusGraph already containerized, but they are not official, and my doubt is more general in order to containerize some apps in a more direct way without the need to research what directories need to be in volume and what not.

I will not redistribute any of this, it's just to my use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a technical level, nothing would stop you from launching a plain container with an attached volume and installing software there.

```
docker run -v my_opt:/opt -it --rm ubuntu sh
```

I wouldn't consider this an especially effective use of Docker.  If your colleague wants to use your database installation, you have no way of giving it to them; if you leave the project for six months and come back to it, you'll have no record of how you built this setup.  If you were set on this approach, you might find the networking and snapshot setups for more typical virtual machines to be better matched to it.